# Laravel & PHP - Output is not the same in Laravel but working on PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im working on a barcode or qrcode generator and I have a problem, when I integrate my code and asset folders in PHP everything works perfectly fine I can generate the code ! , but when I integrate this to Laravel and put all the links it went down tho it is the similar UI but the output of the program is not working well it is not generating the code.

My folders are placed in `public` in laravel and main folder only in php

I am currently confused of this problem - when I delete all assets, codes of JS files in PHP, why is it STILL working tho I deleted all the folders like `fonts` , `css` and `js` however in Laravel when I delete the currently said folders, it brings CHANGES tho in PHP everything works and run even tho the codes are deleted and folders are delete. any solution for this?? im wondering is there a setting for this?

P.S I didnt change any single code of them and still confused why it is not working properly in laravel

Is there any possibility to solve this problem?

my links in laravel

CSS & BOOTSTRAP

```
link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/filereader.js') }}"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/qrcodelib.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/webcodecamjs.js') }}"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
```

links in PHP

CSS

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

JS

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/filereader.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/qrcodelib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webcodecamjs.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For CSS:**

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Make your directory structure is like this for CSS: */public/css/bootstrap.min.css* and */public/css/style.css*

**For Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/filereader.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/qrcodelib.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/webcodecamjs.js') }}"></script>
```

Make your directory structure is like this for JS: */public/js/filereader.js* and */public/js/qrcodelib.js* and */public/js/webcodecamjs.js*

Answer (score 1):

change your CSS/JS Directory Structure in Public folder.

CSS:

```
<link href="{{ asset('filepath') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('filepath') }}"></script>
```